# Is it possible to redirect a mobile device user to m.example on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I would like to have an app on Heroku, but if an user access www.example using a mobile device he would be redirected to m.example.
In this m.example I would have a website which is designed for mobile devices with a button "view the original website". Clicking there, we would see the www.example website.
Is there any way to do that on Heroku?

Thanks!

Edit: @RunscopeAPITools said Heroku itself is irrelevant to the problem and the important thing is the framework. I am developing with .NET and using MONO on Heroku, as described [here](http://friism.com/running-net-on-heroku) . 
According [to the documentation](https://github.com/friism/heroku-buildpack-mono/blob/master/README.md): "It uses nginx as the web server and runs on Mono 3.2."

Edit2: After RunscopeAPITools, I started to get more infos about how to do that using nginx, I will test [this link](http://jyunderwood.com/posts/mobile-redirection-with-nginx.html) and post the results as soon as I can

Edit3: tried this approach by uploading a nginx.conf to Heroku. Nothing happened. Looking in Google I read that is it NOT possible to do that with a config file, only directly on my app. Now I am confused. Can I do that or can't I?

Comment: Heroku is largely irrelevant to solving your problem. The simple answer is 'yes' it's completely possible on Heroku by adding both domains to your app. You may want to post what web framework you're using to get more specific instructions for accomplishing it.

Comment: @RunscopeAPITools tried an approach but didn't work. Further research in Google said I can't accomplish that using a server config. How would you advise me to do that?

Comment: In your ASP.NET app parse the User Agent to detect if it's mobile or not. If so, redirect to m.example.com. Then in your app detect the domain (Request.Host or something similar) and return the mobile templates instead of the regular ones. Maybe this will help? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx

Comment: Yes, I would rather do it before it reaches my app, but it seems that is not possible. Thanks for your reply. Please make it an answer so I can accept it :)